# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths doesn't work however [self.tableView reloadData] does

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using `SWTableViewCell`s and I have a button for deleting the row. usually I would just use the commitEditingStyle and have no problems but with `SWTableViewCell` `rightUtilityButtons` it seems to cause the app to crash. Here's the Code:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[context deleteObject:client];
NSError *error = nil;
if(![context save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"OOPS");
        }else{
            [self.clients removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

This is the error:

> `** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'`

I realize the error is because my datasource is returning a `nil` object. I messed with it a bit and tried a few things. It does work if I remove the `[self.tableView beginUpdates]` and `[self.tableView endUpdates]` and add either `[self.tableView reloadData]` or `[self viewDidAppear:]`, neither of which I like because the cell just blinks out of existence.

My `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` only fires once unless I use `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

What am I doing wrong in order to get `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` working.

*EDIT*
to get cellIndexPath:

```
NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Comment: What is `cellIndexPath`? That is causing the crash, you can't create a literal array with `nil` in it.

Comment: Why do you have your datasource return `nil` instead of an empty array?

Comment: i think that the `not` operator should be removed from here `if(![context save:&error]){`

Comment: Please show your data source methods numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @Snymax Check if `cellIndexPath` is `nil` before you use it.

Comment: sorry about that i edited to show the cellIndexPath. its not updating the numberofRowsInSection i dont mean to return nil. cellIndexPath is not nil like i said i can delete the object from data source the use [self.tableview reloadData]; and it works fine but id like to add the animation to row removal

Comment: I assume `[context deleteObject:client];` is the reason why `cellIndexPath` is nil. Is there any delegate methods that updates table/cell while the context changed?

Comment: @purrninator i dont understand why id need a delegate method to update the table when i remove the object from the context i also remove it from the array and the row. if i need a delegate method to correct this how would i go about doing that

Comment: you don't need the delegate method indeed.

Comment: @purrinator sorry it is if(![context save:&error]){
                NSLog(@"OOPS");
            }else{
                [self.clients removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace

```
    if(![context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"OOPS");
    }else{
        [self.clients removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    }
```

with

```
        if([context save:&error] && cellIndexPath){
            [self.clients removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
```

Comment: This is not quite correct. You should always check the *return value*, and the error only if the return value indicates that the method failed.

Comment: Also it doesn't explain why `cellIndexPath` is `nil`.

Comment: This is right it is my cellIndexPath apparently the cell is not selected when you swipe it. so this doesnt really help my situation but u did figure out why it wasnt working. but i still have no idea how to make it work(Not get a nil on cellIndexPath)

Comment: @Snymax well, you have to change the implementation of SWTableViewCell, I know what I'm talking about because I done this with RMSwipeTableViewCell couple weeks ago having almost the same problem. I don't know exactly how is SWTablecViewCell implemented but anyway I'd recommend you to check whether `selectionStyle` value changed when cell swiped. Also check `setSelected` setter of the cell

Comment: @purrrminator thats what i did i changed the didSwiperight and didSwipeLeft methods to also set the cell as selected... which caused a couple bugs im still working some of it out